# Anaconda Compatibility with Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: anaconda

Is there a way to essentially 'turn on' or activate an anaconda environment without having to edit the ~/.bashrc file each time I run my Remote Desktop Connection?  For reference, there is a dbus issue when the following line in the ~/.bashrc file is not commented out:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/anaconda3:$PYTHONPATH
```

The issue causes the following error message or something similar

```
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus
Connection Refused...
```

Basically, I want to run an Anaconda environment without having it cause connection issues to the Remote Desktop Connection.  What would be a good work-around? Thanks.